# How do I use a List<T> as a data source for a report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, generic-list

In my Visual Studio project I have a class called Person and another class called People.  People contains a public List property.  The Person class holds data about the person pulled in from different databases and files.  Basically the back end is a horrific mess which I have inherited and the Person class pulls it all together.

Now, I'm fairly new to report writing but have successfully designed a few local reports to display data directly from an SQL server but what I want to do here is display the data contained within my List property but I don't know how to do it!  Would someone be able to point me in the right direction by listing the steps I would have to go through to get this to work?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

There are more easy ways to do what you want but if you want to play with List, than probably you can use BindingList instead of List. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx). Also please check LINQ to Objects in Google.